# CSS content based layout

Tags: html, css

I'd like to style a popup (magnific popup) with CSS. It's content is generated via AJAX and contains an image and some text.
If the image is in landscape orientation, it looks very nice, but in portrait orientation it doesn't fit at all, because the image is scaled with `width: 100%`.
The popup classes are doubled, e.g. popupcontainer0 and popupcontainer1, the n

How would I fit this? I searched a lot and tried a lot, but it won't look as I want it to.

I made an image which shows the proportions I want it to have. I also put the relevant part of the document tree into the graphic to make clear, how I did the landscape images.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add orientation specific styles. You following media queries for the same

```
@media screen and (orientation: portrait) {
    // add your portrait styles here
}

@media screen and (orientation:landscape) {
    // add your landscape styles here
}
```

Additionally, you can also add width specific styles like

```
@media screen and (max-device-width : 480px) and (orientation: portrait) {
    // your styles here
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I got that already. My problem at the moment is, that I'm unable to style the popup nicely.

Comment: Okay. Then you need to play around it only to solve your problem. :)